# Panda3d + Bullet using quaternions

Tags: python, bulletphysics, panda3d

I'm not used to use quaternions, it is the first time I'm working with them. Since there aren't examples about using them I've hit a brick wall.

I'm trying to shoot a ball in the mouse direction. If the mouse is closer to the player the shot will have height, if the mouse is further away the shot is low.

Right now I have this:
http://pastebin.com/tgZAU8qV

I've no idea how I can pass a "Z angle" to my quaternion in such way that the shot will be high instead of low. Any ideas how I can achieve this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to rotate around the z axis, wouldn't you just translate it in y/-y direction ?

Comment: That's right it's Y direction.

Comment: But why would you want a rotation? Basicly a quaternion is just a rotation (w) around a specified vector (x,y,z). So if you plan to see the player as the center, looking in the -z direction you just need to adjust the y coordnitate when working with the starting position